# How to add a page redirect in Drupal htaccess file or otherwise?

Tags: 7, redirection, .htaccess

I've built a Drupal website to a replace an old website (not in Drupal) and some of the pages changed urls. I need to create redirects for those pages.

I've thought of using Drupal's `.htaccess` file and have the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/old-page-name$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/new-page-name [L,R=301]
```

But that didn't work.

I've added those lines inside the redirect block in Drupal's htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
```

Just under these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This will be a temporary solution until I install the [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) or some other module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you consider the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module as that "other module" you are looking for. Using an approach as described in my answer to the question "[How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url/170745#170745)" ...

Using that technique, you can also solve your requirement about it being "temporary" (that's just a matter of some appropriate rules **Condition** to be added in your case).