# How to redirect particular page after login via social networking site?

Tags: users, redirection, authentication-authorization, social-network

In my Drupal site I have placed a `link` in checkout page which takes to user/login. On successful login it redirects back to checkout page. For this I have used `?destination=checkout` in the url. I have achieved using form alter

```
function module_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['checkout_message']['#markup'] = t('<a href="/user/login?destination=/checkout">Click to login</a>');
}
```

This redirects to `login` page and then redirects back to `checkout` page, till now it works fine. I have social site login in my login page (for eg., facebook, twitter, google).

How can I redirect the user to checkout if he/she login via social sites? FYI: Above is not working for social network login.

These are the modules used for performing a social login:

- Facebook: [Facebook OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth).
- Twitter, Google+: [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [user_login_destination()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_login_destination/7) for your requirement which third-party authentication modules may use to determine the proper destination after a user has been properly logged in.

```
function user_login_destination() {
  $destination = drupal_get_destination();
  if ($destination['destination'] == 'user/login') {
    $destination['destination'] = 'user';
  }
  return $destination;
}
```

You just need to change line 4 to:

```
$destination['destination'] = '<path you want to go to after login>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to get this to work, using a variation of the sample rule included in my answer to "[How to use the Rules module to implement a custom redirect for an outdated URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170742/how-to-use-the-rules-module-to-implement-a-custom-redirect-for-an-outdated-url/170745#170745)". Here are some modifications you'd need to get it to work for your case also:

- Adapt the URLs to point to your checkout page.
- Add a Rules event specific to the social site they used to perform a login, i.e.:

  - to find out if they used [FBOauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth), you can use the Rules event "User logged in using Facebook connect.", which is an event you can select in Rules after you enable the [Facebook Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_rules) module.
  - to find out if they used [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth), you can use the Rules event "[User logged in through HybridAuth](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/hybridauth/tree/hybridauth.rules.inc#n264)".

By using Rules as detailed above, you probably won't need the custom code anymore that you already have (as mentioned in your question).

To make the value of the URL argument available as a new variable to Rules, you can use the [Rules URL Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

The newly provided Rules actions and conditions can be found under the "URL Argument" conditions and actions groups in the rule configuration interface.

For an example of how to use it, refer to [Comment # 3 in issue # 1686360](https://www.drupal.org/node/1686360#comment-6306112) which is about "*Pass an amount to the url, ie; site/content/node-title?amount=10 or /node-title?=amount:10*". Here is the relevant part of it:

> - add a "Check if URL argument exist" condition to your rule and set the "ARGUMENT" value to "amount".
> - add "Provide URL argument value" action to the rule and set "URL ARGUMENT NAME" value to "amount" and in the "Provided variables" section "ARGUMENT FROM URL - Variable name" to e.g. "`amount_from_url`".
>
> You will now be able to use the amount value as a variable "`amount-from-url`" for other actions in this rule.

**PS**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework), organized in 7 chapters.

Comment: I want to redirect the user only when the url has destination parammeter. Is it possible with rules.

Comment: Sure you can do that too ... Via the Rules URL Argument module (as explained in my updated answer). Good enough?

Comment: In the social login link I have added destination parameter like below url. *https://digi.co/hybridauth/window/Google?destination=gallery&destination_error=user/login*